# does octomap library suit for stereo vision?

Tags: robotic-arm, navigation, octomap, stereo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently, I am participated an ARM navigation program. I obtain point cloud data from stereo vision, and I want to obtain octomap of the environment based on the stereo vision. so i want to know that does octomap library suit for stereo vision? please help me, thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45963/does-octomap-library-suit-for-stereo-vision?/) by [summeryu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3150/summeryu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

OctoMap is more than suited for stereo vision and RGB-D data (e.g. from Kinect or Asus Xtion), in fact it's mainly used on the PR2 to build collision maps from stereo (in the packages [collider](http://www.ros.org/wiki/collider) and [octomap_server](http://www.ros.org/wiki/octomap_server)). Just use the PointCloud2 message type to build maps.

The only limitation might be the amount of data you can insert, I have seen rates of about 10 Hz for tabletop (arm navigation) data. If the insertion / map update gets too slow, you can downsample your data, limit its maximum range in octomap, or increase the octomap resolution (voxel size).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2012-10-17**:
As a clarification: You can limit the maximum range for rays to insert. So if your measurements are 10m away and you are only interested in the near range (say 5m), limiting the max_range of octomap will keep the map more compact and the updates faster.